# Is there a way to have pi in a CSS calc?

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I have an SVG circle animation for a progress bar where the `stroke-dashoffset` is animated from `0,radius` to `radius,0` (for 0% to 100%).

The equation for the length of the circumference of a circle is `pi * d`. Is there a way to use a CSS `calc` function where it can use a value of pi, rather than just a rounded value (like 3.14)?

Comment: As Ouroborus has mentioned browsers mostly round of the numbers to just 2 digits after decimal point so there is not much point in using a value other than 3.14 but if you aren't comfortable with that why not just use `22/7` and let the browser decide how it wants to handle?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to use JavaScript for this animation task: `var intRadius = Math.floor(objCircle.offsetWidth / 2)`

Comment: "The equation for the length of the radius of a circle is pi * d." - I guess you mean *circumference*

Comment: It might be helpful if we knew why you were asking this.

Comment: It's actually impossible to represent an **unrounded** value for pi. [Pi is not rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number)!

Comment: I would be amazed if using an approximation better than 3.14 yielded better visual results.

Comment: Using 3.14 the radius of a circle with d=1000px  will be off by 1px... so it depends how large your circle will be.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is now a [`<calc-constant>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc-constant) `pi` constant that can **only** be used in CSS `calc()` math functions:

```css
.circle {
  --diameter: 3px;
  --circumference: calc(pi * var(--diameter);  <-- `pi`
  stroke-dashoffset: var(--circumference);
}
```

<strike>**However, the [browser support is bad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc-constant#browser_compatibility).**  (As of August 2023, it's only Safari and Firefox.)</strike>

**Actually, November 2023 update**, the support is [currently quite alright!](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_types_calc-constant) (90%+ globally)

---

Instead, you can [use CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) to assign a number to it:

```css
:root {
  --pi: 3.14159265358979;
}

.circle {
  --diameter: 3px;
  --circumference: calc(var(--pi) * var(--diameter));
  stroke-dashoffset: var(--circumference);
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, some browsers (Safari + IE) round to 2 decimals, where Chrome and Firefox can round up to (at least) 4 decimals.

---

Another solution would be to use a preprocessor such as [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) or [Less](https://lesscss.org/) to assign the PI variable to.

For example, using SASS:

```
$pi: 3.14159265358979

.circle {
  --diameter: 3px;
  --circumference: calc(${pi} * var(--diameter));
  stroke-dashoffset: var(--circumference);
}
```

---

Comment: Which is what i've mentioned, and the main reason i've edited in the option of SASS or Less.

Comment: Another option is a CSS transpiler (converts from newer CSS to older CSS) like `cssnext`. Just make sure the "newer CSS" is standards-based, or at least that newer browsers will adopt it, unless you are prepared to change it every couple months.

Answer (score 10):

No.

Consider that the value will be rounded anyway as computers cannot fully realize all numbers. Just use a lengthy approximation for pi:

```
3.141592653589793
```

Comment: Once you've gone that far, you might as well add just one more digit: making the reasonable assumption of IEEE 754 representation for floats, `3.141592653589793` is as good as possible, in the sense that it rounds to the nearest IEEE 754 binary64 value to the true value of π. The value you give will be off by around 7.3 ulps (units in the last place).

Comment: As the comment is so overwhelmingly popular, I have taken the liberty of editing the answer by adding the 15th decimal, as suggested by @MarkDickinson

Comment: Upvoted the comment, currently: 12-10 to the comment.

Answer (score 4):

You can use something approximate, depending the accuracy you need:

22/7 = 3.14

377/120 = 3,142

355/113 = 3,141592

Answer (score 3):

You have an acces to PI variable in sass today. [source](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/math)

```css
@use 'sass:math';

$d: 10;
$yourStuff: math.$pi * $d;
```

However, as others mentioned, it would still be an aproximated PI value, not a real-real PI. It's a decent approximation though:

```
@debug math.$pi; // 3.1415926536
```